# ¿Como cargar un dataGridView enlazado a datos (DataTable) que ya tiene definidas columnas y tamaños por código?

Tags: c#

Al ejecutar el programa se carga el DataGridView con los datos enlazados, pero a continuación de la sexta columna... lo que provoca se solo se vean las filas vacías en el DataGridView... Acá va el código:

```
private void CargarGridDetalle(){
    Detalle detalle = new Detalle();
    detalle.NroPedido = txtNumPedido.Text;
    try{
        dgvDetalle.Refresh();
        dgvDetalle.DataSource = detalle.ListarDetalles(); //DataTable
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show("No se puede cargar información de PEDIDOS: " + ex.Message
            , "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void ConfiguraGrillaDetalle() {
    dgvDetalle.ColumnCount = 6;
    dgvDetalle.Columns[0].Width = 80; dgvDetalle.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Codigo";
    dgvDetalle.Columns[1].Width = 100; dgvDetalle.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Producto";
    dgvDetalle.Columns[2].Width = 80; dgvDetalle.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Precio";
    dgvDetalle.Columns[3].Width = 50; dgvDetalle.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Cantidad";
    dgvDetalle.Columns[4].Width = 50; dgvDetalle.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Descuento";
    dgvDetalle.Columns[5].Width = 80; dgvDetalle.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Total";
}
```

Al mover el scroll horizontal del DataGridView, se pueden ver los registros cargados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: autogeneratecolums esta en false?

Comment: Como te ha dicho @gbianchi, debes poner la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` de tu datagrid a `false`

Comment: Lo hice, pero ahora solo muestra las filas vacías...